# Cherche des stations de radio francophones

Tags: ressources, france, radio

Je cherche des stations de radio francophones qui diffusent de la musique des années 60 et 70 (oldies) ou du métal (death metal préferé), qui ont des animateurs et des programmes d'information.

Je veux améliorer ma compréhension du français parlé.

Pouvez-vous me recommander des stations de radio ?

Comment: "Nostalgie" plays oldies

Comment: http://www.nostalgie.fr/radio-421/

Comment: http://www.francemusique.fr/ (chaîne publique) pop-rock-chanson, jazz -musique du monde, classique & contemporain, pas de death metal. Ré-écoutes possibles. En revanche les morceaux de musique sont présentés, il y a des interviews (en français plutôt soutenu) et les informations nationales. Une sélection d’interprètes et de musiques que l'on entend rarement sur les radios commerciales.

Answer (score 2):

[Classic 21](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classic_21), une radio belge francophone diffuse beaucoup de Rock et Pop-Rock allant des années 50 à aujourd'hui.

Quel bonheur d'entendre du Dire Straits, Pink Floyd, ACDC, etc. sur les ondes !

Answer (score 1):

RFM (musiques et programmes)

Nostalgie comme indiqué dans les commentaires

RMC (beaucoup de programmes, peu de musique)

France Bleu (dépend du département capté, musique variée, et beaucoup de programmes animés)

Europe 1 (Pareil que RMC, avec un peu plus de musique)

Je ne connais, à priori, pas de stations diffusant du death metal

Answer (score 1):

Here is a few radio station you should give a look :

Classic 21 : oldies rock sound (belgian french speaking station) 
OuiFM : lots of rock and alternative rock
Nostalgie : oldies but also french variety